# Hibernate/JPA JOIN using parameter

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have two tables as follows:

```
/* Start of TITLE table */

CREATE TABLE TITLE (
                        ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,         /* Unique Identifier */
                        LANG VARCHAR(3) DEFAULT 'en' ,              /* Language of this entry */
                        NAME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,                  /* Title Name */
                        DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,           /* Selected Language description of title */

                        PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

COMMIT;

ALTER TABLE TITLE ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE (LANG, NAME);
CREATE INDEX TITLE_NAME_LANG ON TITLE (NAME, LANG);

/* End of TITLE table */

/* Start of PERSON table */

CREATE TABLE PERSON (
                          ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,           /* Unique Identifier */
                          FULLNAME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,                /* Person's user input */
                          TITLECODE VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,               /* Reference to TITLE.NAME (FK Key) */

                          PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

INSERT INTO TITLE (LANG, NAME, DESCRIPTION) VALUES
('en', 'MR', 'Mister'),
('en', 'MISS', 'Miss'),
('en', 'MRS', 'Missus'),
/* Insert Spanish versions */
('es', 'MR', 'Señor'),
('es', 'MISS', 'Señorita'),
('es', 'MRS', 'Señora');

COMMIT;
```

I want to be able to load the 'Title' of the person not by ID but by the TITLE.NAME and LANG so that the correct language is loaded.

I have the following model (but unsure about the annotations for Title)

```
@Entity(name = "Title")
@Table(name = "TITLE")
@Data
public class Title {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "LANG")
    private String lang;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

}

@Entity(name = "Person")
@Table(name = "PERSON")
@Data
public class Person {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "FULLNAME")
    private String fullName;

    ///??? what goes here ? @Column(name = "TITLECODE")
    //???
    private Title title;

}


@Data
public class SearchCriteria implements Serializable {

    String lang;        //e.g. 'en', 'es', 'fr', etc.

}
```

How can I add 'SearchCriteria' to the query so that it's ignored for the 'Person' table (because that doesn't contain 'lang' property but is accessible for the join on the 'Title' field?
And of course, what should be the annotations on the Title field in the Person class?

Comment: SearchCriteria is a bad idea - how are you going to insert a Person object and have it reference a Title, or change it? What happens if someone changes their language preference? IMO you should always map your objects to the data as it is in the database, and let the application filter out based on language if that is what is required. Get a person and the list of titles, and select the one you want to use from that. Person should have a 1:M (a list/set) to title using the TITLECODE as fk to Title.name, and a separate basic mapping to TITLECODE so you can set it directly

Answer (score 0):

Why not try

```
@Entity(name = "Person")
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "FULLNAME")
    private String fullName;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="NAME", referencedColumnName="TITLECODE", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    @MapKey(name = "lang")
    private Map<String,Title> titles;

    @Column(name= "TITLECODE")
    private String titleCode;//use this to modify the FK value directly

}
```

This allows you to get Person instances as they exist in the DB, and you can filter out the language from the map yourself.  If you must build a view object over it, add in a transient 'title' property to serialize to the client, and use a JPQL query of the form:

```
"Select new Person(p.id, p.fullName, VALUE(titleMap)) where Person p join p.titles titleMap where  VALUE(titleMap).lang = :lang"
```

Such a DTO though probably only wants the language specific DESCRIPTION property from the Title, and not a full title reference:

```
  "Select new PersonDTO(p.id, p.fullName, VALUE(titleMap).description) where Person p join p.titles titleMap where  VALUE(titleMap).lang = :lang"
```